# $f$ convex, $M$ subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then $x = argmin_{x \in M} f(x)$ $\iff$ $\nabla f(x) \perp M$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, convex-analysis

I am trying to solve the following exercise, which I found in some online lecture notes on convex functions ([https://sites.math.washington.edu/~ddrusv/crs/Math_516/bookwithindex.pdf](https://sites.math.washington.edu/%7Eddrusv/crs/Math_516/bookwithindex.pdf), page 18):

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ be a smooth convex function and $M \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a linear subspace.
Then $x = argmin_{x \in M} f(x)$ $\iff$ $\nabla f(x) \perp M$.

I am able to prove one implication but not the other. I use the fact that, since $f$ is convex, we have
$$
f(y) \geq f(x) + \nabla f(x)^\top (y-x) \quad \forall y \in M.
$$
Then, if $\nabla f (x) \perp M$, we have $\nabla f(x)^\top (y-x) = 0$ and hence $f(y) \geq f(x)$ for all $y \in M$.

I have problems with the other implication.

I would like to use the above convexity inequality together with the fact that
$$
f(y) \geq f(x) \quad \forall y \in M
$$
but I do not come up with a smart way to put them together. Can someone help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The convexity of $f$ is not needed for the implication in the other direction. Assume that $x \in M$ and
$$
 f(x) = \min \{ f(y) \mid y \in M \} \,.
$$
If $h \in M$ then the function
$$
 \Bbb R \ni t \mapsto \phi(t) = f(x + th)
$$
is differentiable and has a minimum at $t = 0$. It follows that
$$
 0 = \phi'(0) = \nabla f(x)^T \cdot h \, .
$$
This holds for all $h \in M$, so that $\nabla f(x) \perp M$.